# GUI Partitioning tool for Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

What is the best GUI partitioning tool for Ubuntu?

Comment: Does fdisk in an xterm count?

Comment: @Kyle Doesn't support GPT, but I'd say cfdisk is pretty good otherwise - straight fdisk isn't really a gui :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gparted is nice, and <del>included by default on Ubuntu.</del> Lets you do just about everything you should need. 
My bad, it isn't included by default on my install of 10.04, I thought it was. It IS however, in the repos. Gparted also has a liveCD in case you need to resize your root partition or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Kparted is extremely nice, but requires installation of the KDE libraries.